# Better cast an element of a list or use a pointer to it?

Tags: c++, pointers

Say I have a struct like this

```
struct MyStruct
{
  int a;
  int b;
  string str;
  [...and so on...]
};
```

Now I have a pointer to a list of this structures

```
List<MyStruct*>* MyList;
```

and I need to use this elements in a `for-loop`. To access an element in the `for-loop` I need to do something like this

```
((MyStruct)MyList[i])->a
```

**In terms of performance** is it better to do this way (i.e. with a cast) or is it better to use a pointer to the element, i.e. I declare a pointer before the `for-loop` and then each time I do this

```
//Before the for-loop
MyStruct* s;

//Inside the for-loop
for(...)
{
  s = MyList[i];
  s->a;
  ...
}
```

Comment: dont cast if its not needed.

Comment: it's a List type from System::Collection::Generic from Visual C++

Comment: A List of what? Could you show us the declaration?

Comment: @MaksimSolovjov no its classified

Comment: Done. I edited the description

Comment: Just use `(*MyList)[i]->a` then, you don't need any casts

Comment: like i said, no cast is needed, follow this rule: don't cast if you don't know why you need a cast and you'll be fine in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<MyStruct*>* MyList;
```

Since `MyList` is a pointer to a list of `MyStruct*`, you don't need to cast. What you do need is to dereference `MyList` before you index it:

```
(*MyList)[i]->a
```

Comment: a questions here, std::list doesn't have the operator[] so what container are you and TS refering to?